# How to combine all arguments in two lists if the first element of each list is the same

Tags: django

```
setting = Subject.objects.annotate(A_setup=Count('id', filter=Q(type='A'), distinct=True) * Value(50),
                      B_setup=Count('id', filter=Q(type='B'), distinct=True) * Value(30),
                      C_setup=Count('id', filter=(~Q(type='A') & ~Q(type='B') & ~Q(type__isnull=True) & Q(id__in=workers.filter(worker=1).values('id')))) * Value(10)) \
            .values('setting__user_id', 'A_setup', 'B_setup', 'C_setup')

setting = [{'setting__user_id': 4, 'A_setting': 50.0, 'B_setting': 120, 'C_setting': 10.0}, {'setting__user_id': 34, 'A_setting': 0.0, 'B_setting': 0, 'C_setting': 0.0}, {'setting__user_id': 33, 'A_setting': 0.0, 'B_setting': 150, 'C_setting': 0.0}, {'setting__user_id': 30, 'A_setting': 0.0, 'B_setting': 150, 'C_setting': 0.0}, {'setting__user_id': 74, 'A_setting': 50.0, 'B_setting': 120, 'C_setting': 10.0}]


uploader = Feedback.objects           .values('uploader_id').distinct().values_list('uploader_id')
uploader = [{'uploader_id': 25}, {'uploader_id': 20}, {'uploader_id': 74}, {'uploader_id': 34}, {'uploader_id': 93}, {'uploader_id': 88}, {'uploader_id': 73}, {'uploader_id': 89}, {'uploader_id': 30}, {'uploader_id': 33}, {'uploader_id': 85}, {'uploader_id': 4}, {'uploader_id': 46}]
```

"setting" outputs only users who satisfy the conditions. But I need a list of all users. The "uploader" is a queryset containing all users. First, the entire list of users is printed, and if the user's id is included in the "setting", the setting value is output. The final result I want to achieve is as follows.

```
Desired Result: [['25', '0', '0', '0'], ['20', '0', '0', '0'], ['74', '50', '120', '10'], ['34', '0', '0', '0'], ['93', '0', '0', '0'], ['88', '0', '0', '0'], ['73', '0', '0', '0'], ['89', '0', '0', '0'], ['30', '0', '150', '0'], ['33', '0', '150', '0'], ['35', '0', '0', '0'], ['4', '50', '120', '10'], ['46', '0', '0', '0']]
```

sorry. Please check again. There are two querysets. I want to get the A_setup, B_setup, C_setup values ​​of setting if uploader id and uploader id of setting are the same after unfolding the uploader queryset, and adding 0 if there is no uploader id in setting.
How do I get the results I want?

Comment: What have you tried? What issues did you come up against? Please edit your question and include code of what you've done so far.

Comment: I can't see any changes to your question, only an additional tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it is better to change the data structure a little bit (into `setting_new` and `uploader_ids` below), and then use list comprehension:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

# setting = [{'setting__user_id': 4, 'A_setting': 50.0, 'B_setting': 120, 'C_setting': 10.0}, ...
# uploader = [{'uploader_id': 25}, {'uploader_id': 20}, {'uploader_id': 74}, ...

setting_new = {dct['setting__user_id']: itemgetter('A_setting', 'B_setting', 'C_setting')(dct) for dct in setting}
uploader_ids = map(itemgetter('uploader_id'), uploader)

output = [[i, *setting_new.get(i, (0,0,0))] for i in uploader_ids]
print(output)
# [[25, 0, 0, 0], [20, 0, 0, 0], [74, 50.0, 120, 10.0], [34, 0.0, 0, 0.0], ...
```

Comment: I think I've reached 90% of the results I want to get. thank you! However, if setting_new contains uploader_id, I need to pull the A_setting, B_setting, C_setting values ​​of setting_new. All arguments after each uploader id must not be 0.

Comment: @leesuccess Did you check the output? Check the third sublist, for example.